# I have an image, how do i change it to pure black and white such that only a specific colour becomes white

Tags: python, opencv

Only the coloured stuff stays the same colour, like if I have a dark background, white text but one bit of text is light green #00FF00, how do I change it to a pure black and white image like normal, but only that specific green becomes white?

The name of the image I want to work on is 'download.png'

Here is my current code for reference:

```
originalImage = cv2.imread('download.png')
grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(originalImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)(thresh, blackAndWhiteImage) = cv2.threshold(grayImage, 80, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
im = Image.fromarray(blackAndWhiteImage)
im.save('download.png')
```

The above code just turns the image pure black and white based on a threshold of the brightness of 80/255. I want to replace this threshold with a specific colour (#00FF00)

Comment: can u provide a sample image?

Comment: See cv2.inRange() to threshold on a color (or color range)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User [fmw42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7355741/fmw42) said I need to use cv2.inRange to threshold on a colour. This works.